# 2.0 Suitelet With Custom Function From 1.0 Client Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Can 2.0 Suitelet use functions from a 1.0 Client Script?

### Update

As per my colleagues, it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

As per my colleagues, we cannot implement a suitelet 2 and a client script 1. Compatible version is both should be on the same version.